# Steam blocking other software installation

Tags: steam

I've tried to unninstall Steam by typing *sudo apt-get purge steam* and also *remove steam*. When I *apt-get update*, I get an error in the Steam repo:

Err http://repo.steampowered.com precise/steam amd64 Packages

and also

Err http://repo.steampowered.com precise/steam i386 Packages

Anytime I try to install another software, I can't. Does anyone knows how can I fix this?

Comment: `Anytime I try to install another software, I can't.`
Can you tell us why? What errors do you see?

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to remove Steam, you need to remove the corresponding line(s) from your /etc/apt/sources.lst file and then `apt-get update`.

Comment: And which lines are that?

Comment: I never used Steam, most probably there's a line containing the word 'steam'...